# Brake warning light glows faintly

Tags: brakes, indicators

Earlier this day, my brake warning light stayed on at half brightness after I disengage the e-brake. The stopping power doesn't seem to be affected. After a few minutes with the engine running, the indicator fades away. My braking fluid looks topped up properly. What could be causing this?

My car is a 2003 Toyota KF-71.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came back from a repair shop and it turns out the fluid sensor was malfunctioning. They've unplugged it for now, until I can find a new one. Now the light only comes up if the e-brake is engaged or (hopefully) when something else goes wrong in the system.

Answer (score 1):

This could be either a wire rubbing somewhere on the body or it is a pad warning sensor - the wire is just starting to come into contact signalling low pads.

You should check the pads for wear.

Answer (score 1):

In case your car has only one brake warning light (some cars have two: one for e-brake, one for the brake system), it also could be a bad contact in the e-brake switch. If you are able to reach it (located underneath the e-brake lever), take it out and clean it.